# How to add icon to top navbar in react-native-navigation?

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

**Issue Description**

I'm trying to add a plus icon to the right side of the top navbar, i'm using react-native-navigation library by wix.
I get this error

> Bundling `index.android.js`  [development, non-minified, hmr enabled] 
>   0.0% (3/662), failed. error: bundling failed: "TransformError F:/work/www/native/project8/wixnav/img/navicon_add2x.png: Unexpected
>   character '�' (1:0)
>   [F:\work\www\native\project8\wixnav\img\navicon_add2x.png]"
>
> > 1 | �PNG
> >         | ^   2 |    3 |   4 | IHDR   #   #    6���   tRNS ���   IDATxc�Ϡ��!

**Steps to Reproduce**

I followed the [documentation](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/adding-buttons-to-the-navigator?id=adding-buttons-to-the-navigator) , I only wanted to add an icon button, so I added this in the class before the constructor:

```
  static navigatorButtons = {
    rightButtons: [
      {
        icon: require('../../../img/navicon_add2x.png'),
        id: 'add'
      }
    ]
  };
```

**Environment**

- React Native Navigation version: 1.1.235
- React Native version:0.47.1
- Platform: Android
- Device info: Real Device, KitKat 4.4.2, Debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved when I upgraded to version 1.1.436, which is the latest right now.